# Sending multiple files function only sends the last file in a list and ignores the others

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, mime

I have a function that emails multiple files as attachment.

But for some reason it only send the last file specified in a list:

```
files=['AlignEnvironmentalPremium.txt', 'TestFile.xlsx']
```

It will only send `TestFile.xlsx` and ignore `AlignEnvironmentalPremium.txt`

Do I need to change something in a code so it would send all files in a list and not just the last one?

```
import os
from base64 import decodebytes 
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import encoders
import datetime

send_from = 'sendfrom@.usercom'
send_to = ['sendto@.usercom']
cc = ['copyto@.usercom']
rcpt = COMMASPACE.join(send_to).split(',') +  COMMASPACE.join(cc).split(',')
subject = 'Monthly Audit Report' 
text = 'Hello, \nPlease, see attached'
files=['AlignEnvironmentalPremium.txt', 'TestFile.xlsx']

# below function sends email
def send_mail(send_from,rcpt,subject,text ,files):
    assert isinstance(send_to, list)
    assert isinstance(cc, list)
    assert isinstance(files, list)
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg["From"] = send_from
    msg["To"] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
    msg['Cc'] = COMMASPACE.join(cc)
    msg["Date"] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg["Subject"] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
    if files is not None:
        for f in files:
            part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
            part.set_payload(open(f, "rb").read())
            encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header(
                "Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(f)
            )   
        msg.attach(part)
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP('0.0.0.0: 25')
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, rcpt, msg.as_string())     
    smtp.close()
send_mail(send_from,rcpt,subject,text,files)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the email library so maybe there's a nuance I'm missing, however I think this simply a syntax slip-up.

You're creating an instance of MIMEBase for each file and calling it `part`. At the end of your for loop the value of `part` will be the last file that you iterated over. Since `msg.attach(part)` is outside your for loop you will only be attaching the last file in your list of files.

I think you know where to go from here.

Comment: Oh!   Thanks for quick respond!